# IdeaPad 5G-14Q8X05 ubuntu support

Tags: drivers, kernel, lenovo, laptop, arm64

I am new here. I bought a lenovo IdeaPad 5G-14Q8X05 which has the qualcomm snapdragon 8cx gen 2 aka SC8180XP and as far as I know it is currently not supported by the linux kernel. While the snapdragon 8cx gen 3 aka [SC8280](https://git.linaro.org/landing-teams/working/qualcomm/kernel.git/log/?qt=grep&q=SC8280) has complete support starting from linux 5.19+ and snapdragon 8cx gen 1 aka [SC8180X](https://git.linaro.org/landing-teams/working/qualcomm/kernel.git/log/?qt=grep&q=SC8180X) should have it from [linux 6.1+](https://git.linaro.org/landing-teams/working/qualcomm/kernel.git/commit/?id=40285e64c5654c956505dad34ed2ee4be163b1f0).
Once the snapdragon 8cx gen 2 has the kernel support, what about drivers? I read about this project [Porting Linux to AArch64 Laptops](https://www.linaro.org/blog/porting-linux-to-aarch64-laptops/) which supports few [devices](https://github.com/aarch64-laptops/build#device-status).

What is the status of Ubuntu? Are you planning to support it?

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will my device work with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/986878/will-my-device-work-with-ubuntu)

Comment: Thank you, I found that I have to wait the kernel 6.1.

Comment: The 6.1 Linux kernel will not be supported in upcoming Ubuntu 23.04 except for via PPAs.

Comment: I installed the latest debian unstable with kernel 6.1 and now the installation procedure works in both GUI and text mode, although the mouse and keyboard do not work.

Comment: I discovered that the non-free debian firmware-qcom-soc https://packages.debian.org/sid/firmware-qcom-soc does not include drivers for SoC gen 1-2, but only those for gen 3. So to get all the drivers, I have to wait for https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/.

Comment: Did you get it to work with 22.04? Ubuntu 23.04 incl. Kernel 6.2 is being launched this week. Would be good to know if this version also fails to support this device fully. Thx

Comment: I have not yet been able to try with kernrl 6.2. However they are working on having support in the mainline kernel for the lenovo flex 5g which is the folding version twin of the lenovo IdeaPad 5G-14Q8X05 (same SoC). Excellent https://www.phoronix.com/news/Lenovo-Flex-5G-Linux-Mainline